# SQL Strange Timeout Issue

Tags: sql-server, exec

Ok, so I am trying to create a procedure that call an extended procedure. I am getting the following error:

```
Msg 121, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)
```

Even with the simplest test I get that error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
AS
BEGIN

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir *.exe'

END
```

However if I just run `xp_cmdshell 'dir *.exe'` by itself it works.

This is running on a clustered SQL 2005 server. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What if you CREATE PROC with just a "SELECT 1"?

Comment: Creating PROC's is not a problem. I have literally a thousands.

Comment: I'll ask again... The question says "get error on create". The comment says "Creating PROC's is not a problem". So, you only get the error on CREATE for this stored proc?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the procedure, the problem lies with the EXEC statement, when that is included it gives the error. Since I cannot call `xp_cmdshell` without it it is needed. This also occurs if I try to include it and update with `ALTER`.

Comment: Down vote? What is wrong with this question? It is a legitimate issue without an a known cause.

Comment: +1, this question is legitimate.

Comment: Thanks Abe, still no luck on this.

Comment: Complete longshot guess but do you have any security software on the network that might not like the phrase `xp_cmdshell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting the error when you CREATE the procedure or when you EXECUTE it?

If you get it when you execute it, then there could be some issue with permissions. Since in later versions of sql server calling `xp_cmdshell` is tightly locked down and by default not enabled in the surface area configuration, I could see a potential for this.

How are you calling the SP? If you're using dynamic SQL, then know that it executes with the privileges of the caller, not the SP creator.

Do you need to prefix the SP with master as in `master.dbo.xp_cmdshell`?

Have you tried `EXECUTE AS` either in the SP creation or in the SP execution?

Also, in my experience, transport-level errors are sometimes not due to a problem with the server but a problem with the client caching its connection object past the time when the server has dropped it (thus invalidating the connection object). Given that you're presumably running this within just a short time of initially connecting, it doesn't sound like that is the exact problem, but could you be having some kind of proxy/firewall/net filter issue that is dropping packets because of detecting certain keywords in the packets? I know this is a long shot but I had to ask...

Comment: I am not sure if the cause is what you stated, but closest thing I could find. It will run sometimes and fail others.